# Adjust save location of Custom XCom Backend on a per task basis

Tags: airflow

I have posted a discussion question about this here as well https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/19868

Is it possible to specify arguments to a custom xcom backend? If I could force a task to return data (pyarrow table/dataset, pandas dataframe) which would save a file in the correct container with a "predictable file location" path, then that would be amazing. A lot of my custom operator code deals with creating the blob_path, saving the blob, and pushing a list of the blob_paths to xcom.

- Since I work with many clients, I would prefer to have the data for Client A inside of the client-a container which uses a different SAS
- When I save a file I consider that a "stage" of the data so I would prefer to keep it, so ideally I could provide a blob_path which matches the folder structure I generally use

```
class WasbXComBackend(BaseXCom):
    def __init__(
        self,
        container: str = "airflow-xcom-backend",
        path: str = guid(),
        partition_columns: Optional[list[str]] = None,
        existing_data_behavior: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.container = container
        self.path = path
        self.partition_columns = partition_columns
        self.existing_data_behavior = existing_data_behavior

    @staticmethod
    def serialize_value(self, value: Any):
        if isinstance(value, pd.DataFrame):
            hook = AzureBlobHook(wasb_conn_id="azure_blob")
            with io.StringIO() as buf:
                value.to_csv(path_or_buf=buf, index=False)
                hook.load_string(
                    container_name=self.container,
                    blob_name=f"{self.path}.csv",
                    string_data=buf.getvalue(),
                )
            value = f"{self.container}/{self.path}.csv"
        elif isinstance(value, pa.Table):
            hook = AzureBlobHook(wasb_conn_id="azure_blob")
            write_options = ds.ParquetFileFormat().make_write_options(
                version="2.6", use_dictionary=True, compression="snappy"
            )
            written_files = []
            ds.write_dataset(
                data=value,
                schema=value.schema,
                base_dir=f"{self.container}/{self.path}",
                format="parquet",
                partitioning=self.partition_columns,
                partitioning_flavor="hive",
                existing_data_behavior=self.existing_data_behavior,
                basename_template=f"{self.task_id}-{self.ts_nodash}-{{i}}.parquet",
                filesystem=hook.create_filesystem(),
                file_options=write_options,
                file_visitor=lambda x: written_files.append(x.path),
                use_threads=True,
                max_partitions=2_000,
            )
            value = written_files
        return BaseXCom.serialize_value(value)

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize_value(self, result) -> Any:
        result = BaseXCom.deserialize_value(result)
        if isinstance(result, str) and result.endswith(".csv"):
            hook = AzureBlobHook(wasb_conn_id="azure_blob")
            with io.BytesIO() as input_io:
                hook.get_stream(
                    container_name=self.container,
                    blob_name=str(self.path),
                    input_stream=input_io,
                )
                input_io.seek(0)
                return pd.read_csv(input_io)
        elif isinstance(result, list) and ".parquet" in result:
            hook = AzureBlobHook(wasb_conn_id="azure_blob")
            return ds.dataset(
                source=result, partitioning="hive", filesystem=hook.create_filesystem()
            )
        return result
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what information you want to be able to retrieve to use as part of your "predictable file location".  But there is [a PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19505) to pass basic things like dag_id, task_id etc on to `serialize_value` so that you can use them when naming your stored objects.

Until that is merged, you'll have to override `BaseXCom.set`.

Comment: Added a more complete example. Since the primary way I save data on Azure is as partitioned parquet datasets, I would hope to be able to control the full path of the dataset, and some arguments like which column the data should be partitioned by etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override BaseXCom.set

a working ,in production example

```py
class MyXComBackend(BaseXCom):
    @classmethod
    @provide_session
    def set(cls, key, value, execution_date, task_id, dag_id, session=None):
        session.expunge_all()

        # logic to use this custom_xcom_backend only with the necessary dag and task
        if cls.is_task_to_custom_xcom(dag_id, task_id):
            value = cls.custom_backend_saving_fn(value, dag_id, execution_date, task_id)
        else:
            value = BaseXCom.serialize_value(value)

        # remove any duplicate XComs
        session.query(cls).filter(
            cls.key == key, cls.execution_date == execution_date, cls.task_id == task_id, cls.dag_id == dag_id
        ).delete()

        session.commit()

        # insert new XCom
        from airflow.models.xcom import XCom  # noqa
        session.add(XCom(key=key, value=value, execution_date=execution_date, task_id=task_id, dag_id=dag_id))

        session.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def is_task_to_custom_xcom(dag_id: str, task_id: str) -> bool:
        return True # custom your logic here if necessary
```